# Can't create new folder or paste anything in my second drive

Tags: directory

[image]I did installed my ubuntu in SSD and attach HDD for storing regular data, but i can't create either any folder or paste anything in my HDD. i am in dilemma... [image]

Comment: Linux works with permissions and owners. The owner of your HDD may be root. You will need to change it to your own user.

Comment: I tried this code before, but sadly it didn't worked for me. Anyway thank you.

Comment: You will need to provide details on the attached HDD: is that a removable drive or not? Did you mount it using fstab or is it automatically mounted when you connect the drive? What is the file system?

Comment: 1) It is an attached HDD.  2) frankly speaking i don't know meaning of your second question (i'm a newbie in linux) .    3) NTFS file system for HDD partitions.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably a permissions issue. 
Have you tried to create a new folder using the command line?

```
sudo mkdir new_folder
```

If this works, the problem is the lack of permissions. 
You will have to give permissions to your HDD:

```
chmod u+rw path_to_hard_drive
```

Comment: Best not to use 777, that gives read/write & execute to everyone (like Windows does) including that hacker. Part of advantage of Linux is permissions where you can restrict who can do what. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting/1013700#1013700

Answer (score 2):

This Problem is probably due that you've Dual Boot, the windows OS still opened

To Handle this problem, you have to shut down the Windows OS by executing this command on CMD
`shutdown /s`

Or Another Way, you might use the Power Option to deactivate it
Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 1):

If you have dual boot, in my case are Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04

your Windows OS might hasn't been completely shutdown.

You can read this article :

> 2 ways to perform a windows full shutdown :
>
> https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/2-ways-to-perform-a-full-shutdown.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1224487)

Comment: Ahh i see, thanks for the advice :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo nautilus
```

Other Locations > Select drive that you wanna access > Right click > Properties > Permission

There change the Owner and group to your username, also check the Access it should be "Create and delete files"

[demo pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkEIs.png)

Comment: The OP says he is a complete newbe where are the commands to change the ownership he wont know them.

Comment: It only have one command then is all graphical interface.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open problematic drive in Windows before the issue?
If so, try ntfsfix.

Find a drive device name:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Unmout drive from nautilus.
Then fix it:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdc1
```

Mount the drive again.